# FunctionContinuous for a function defined with Which

Tags: discontinuity

The function:

```
f[x_] := Which[0 <= x < 1/2, x^2, 1/2 <= x <= 1, x^2 + (x - 1/2)^3];
```

is continuous on the interval $0 \leq x \leq 1$, as a simple `Plot` will show.

Why won't the following evaluate to `True`?

```
FunctionContinuous[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

Comment: `FunctionDiscontinuities[f[x], x]` reports `x == 0 || x == 1/2 || x == 1`.

Comment: @Syed:  Yes... thanks.  But the function *IS* continuous in the full closed range [0,1]... right?

Comment: You're right it's continuous. But FunctionContinuous seems not to work so well with `Which`, for example, `FunctionContinuous[
 {Which[x > -10, 1], 0 <= x <= 1},
 x
 ]` does not evaluate. It seems to work better with `Piecewise`.

Comment: @Diffycue:  Hmmm.... doesn't seem to work with `Piecewise` either.

Comment: My guess is that, like other control-flow statements, `Which` does not evaluate the branches of the conditional that are not realized. So whatever `FunctionContinuous` is doing, perhaps, involves a comparison between two forms only one of which is evaluated and therefore they appear inequivalent.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Roughly speaking, `Piecewise` is more suitable for math-related programming. (But there does exist a tendency that math-related functions are handling `If`, `Which`, etc. better and better these years. Sadly I can't recall an example for the moment. )

Luckily, when math-related functions cannot handle `If`, `Which`, etc. well, we can use `PiecewiseExpand` to transform them to `Piecewise`:

```
FunctionContinuous[{f[x] // PiecewiseExpand, 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
(* True *)
```

BTW, even `Piecewise` cannot be handled well in some cases, then `` Simplify`PWToUnitStep `` may be your friend. Just search in this site, and you'll see some interesting examples.

Comment: Several helpful comments here.  Yours works well, soo.... $\checkmark$.

Answer (score 3):

My guess is that `Which` is more of a control flow statement than a method of specifying mathematical functions. I found that it works with Piecewise:

```
f[x_] := Piecewise[
  {
   {x^2, 0 <= x < 1/2},
   {x^2 + (x - 1/2)^3, 1/2 <= x <= 1}
   }
  ]
FunctionContinuous[
 {f[x], 0 <= x <= 1},
 x
 ]
```

Answer (score 2):

As workaround, use `Piecewise` instead of `Which`. There seems be an issue with `Which`

```
f[x_] :=  Piecewise[{{x^2, 0 <= x < 1/2}, {x^2 + (x - 1/2)^3, 1/2 <= x <= 1}}]
g[x_] :=  Which[0 <= x < 1/2, x^2, 1/2 <= x <= 1, x^2 + (x - 1/2)^3, True, 0];

Plot[{f[x], g[x]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Plot[{g[x], g[x]}, {x, -1, 1}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
FunctionContinuous[{f[x], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
(* True *)

FunctionContinuous[{g[x], 0 <= x <= 1}, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

V 13.3.1 on windows 10.